# Always show toolbars in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, toolbar, macros

I have a custom toolbar associated with some VBA macros in Word 2003. I want this toolbar to alway be visible, independent of the doc or template open.

Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: 12 year old version of word eh? I guess if it aint broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Sorry, it's 2003, it was 97 but we recently updated. Not to 2007, not so crazy!.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an add-in containing the commandbar you need that will load with Word, regardless of the file that is opened.  There are not many guides on the 'net exlpaining this specifically for Word, but the process is very similar to other Office programs that are more commonly modified in this way, such as Excel.

A primer on how to create a Word add-in [is here](http://www.bettersolutions.com/word/WCA723/NI825618332.htm), and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165073(office.10).aspx) shows a module that will add a commmandbar to a Word add-in.  There are many more Excel resources and the coommandbar object model exactly or almost identical between Excel & Word so you should be able to utilise these if you get stuck.